# Firing same onclick function of multiple anchor tags using loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I am trying to fire **onclick** event of multiple `<a>` tags one after another using `.each()` loop.
The first click is working fine but the others are not working.

The `<a>` has same class with different Id and function parameters

```
<div id="outerDiv">
<div><a class="AnchorDiv" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument('firstdocumentpath', 'listnerUrl', null); " style="display: none;" id="docId1"></a></div><div><a class="AnchorDiv" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument('firstdocumentpath', 'listnerUrl', null); " style="display: none;" id="docId2"></a></div><div><a class="AnchorDiv" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument('seconddocumentpath', 'listnerUrl', null); " style="display: none;" id="docId3"></a></div><div><a class="AnchorDiv" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument('thirddocumentpath', 'listnerUrl', null); " style="display: none;" id="DocId4"></a></div><div>
```

The code I have tried which opens only first document

```
 $("#outerDiv .AnchorDiv").each(function (e) {
        $(this).click();
    })
```

Comment: Define what *"opens document"* means in more detail. If it means in a new tab...probably a browser restriction allowing opening multiple tabs without user event. If it means in same window...can only open one at a time

Comment: its opening document in same window with the IT-Hit ajax library

Comment: Is there something we can do to achieve it ?

Comment: Actually not sure what that library does. Not enough detail provided in question to really help here without a [mcve] and a better explanation of what is expected